# SQlite UPDATE operation not working ionic 3

Tags: sqlite, ionic3

I am using ionic 3 in my project with SQLite database. i have had all the other CRUD operations working except for the UPDATE with this code

```
this.sqlite.create({
        name: 'nearbye.db',
        location: 'default'
      }).then((db: SQLiteObject)=>{
        db.executeSql('UPDATE chats SET read=? WHERE read=?', ['time','checked']).then(res =>{
             console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
            }).catch(e => alert(JSON.stringify(e)))
        }).catch(e => alert(JSON.stringify(e)));
```

My sample data in db is

```
{"id":35,"textFrom":"xxxx","textTo":"xxxx","message":"15","time":1540823439874,"read":"time","image":"","friend":"xxxx"},
{"id":36,"textFrom":"xxxx","textTo":"xxxx","message":"16","time":1540823441705,"read":"time","image":"","friend":"xxxx"}
```

The query returns `{"rows":{"length":0},"rowsAffected":0}`
despite that i have rows that match the criteria. Please help!

Comment: In both cases, `read` has a value of `"time"`. Your query has the clause `WHERE read = 'checked'` unless I'm misunderstanding something, I think you just have your arguments backwards.

Comment: wow, thanks! i didn't notice that for like 3 hours. Thank you so much